# JMESPath search nested data for key

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jmespath

I am trying to use the Python Library for JMESPath to extract information from a large JSON file, a much simplified example is here:

```json
{
  "high_name":"test",
  "sections":[
     {
        "name":"section1",
        "item":"string1"
     },
     {
        "name":"section2",
        "item":"string2",
        "items_sub":[
           {
              "item":"deeper string1"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get an output as such:

```json
{
  "high_name":"test",
  "sections":[
     {
        "name":"section1",
        "items":[
           "string1"
        ]
     },
     {
        "name":"section2",
        "items":[
           "string1",
           "deeper string1"
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

The deeper string can be from 1 to 3 levels deep depending on the type of section. I need to search the keys to get all the matching `item` names.

I have done this successfully using jsonpath-rw-ext but want to know if it is possible with JMESPath to remove the reliance on two libraries?

I can't seem to find a way to search all sub keys regardless of their level in JMESPath.

Working string for JSONPATH-RW-EXT:

```
$.sections[*]..item
```

Best attempt with JMESPath (doesn't work):

```
sections[*].*.item
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Riccardo79 no sorry... I gave up and honestly can't remember what I did instead.